# .Net Entity Framework - let keyword with a condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I need to make a if-else statement in the query meaning I only want to add the OpenAmount to ExpectedAmount if the type = Cash, the problem is that it only gives me the cash row not the other row.

```
 Dim TenderList = (From t In EnData.BatchRecs 
                   Join b In EnData.RegShifts 
                   On t.BatchID Equals b.RegShiftID 
                   Where t.BatchID = ID 
                   Let ExpectedAmount = (t.ExpectedAmount + b.OpeningAmount) 
                   Where t.TenderName = "CASH"
                   Select t.BatchRecID, ExpectedAmount, t.ExpectedCount, 
                      t.PickUpAmount, t.TenderName, OverShort, 
                      t.PickUpCount, t.TenderID)
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a conditional statement.

```
Let ExpectedAmount = If(t.TenderName = "CASH",
                        t.ExpectedAmount + b.OpeningAmount,
                        t.ExpectedAmount)
```

You also don't need `Where t.TenderName = "CASH"` if you do this.

Comment: Your the best! Thanks so much